# Lambda Expressing Trouble understanding MSDN example

Tags: c#, lambda

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);  
foreach (var sD in shortDigits)  
{  
    Console.WriteLine(sD);  
}
```

MSDN gives the above example of code  I understand that "digit" represents one of the strings in the array. What I don't understand is how does the Lambda expression know that the second parameter is the index of the string in the array.

Comment: What do you mean by `know`? The second parameter contains the index because that is what is passed to it by `Where`, just as the first is the element in the source sequence.

Comment: Because it's in the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

A Lambda expression always consist out of two parts:

- In front of the lambda operator `=>` are the input parameter(s). In your case, the `.Where` operation gives a string and an integer called `(digit, index)`.
- After the lambda operator is the code to return a bool (by working with the two parameters). You could also write it like:

All in all, you can understand the expresison like this function:

```
bool WhereDigits(string digit, int index)
{
    return digit.Length < index;
}
```

Means, the function returns true for all digits with a lower length than their arrayindex.

Answer (score 1):

> how does the Lambda expression know that the second parameter is the index of the string in the array

Lambda expression does not know that. `Where` extension method knows because the way it was implemented.

Lambda just takes some parameters to do your job. who sends the parameters ? `Where` extension method as you can see below.

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> WhereIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate) {
    int index = -1;
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        checked { index++; }

        if (predicate(element, index)) // the element and index is being sent to the function. your function executes here.
             yield return element;
    }
}
```

The parameters then are given here to run your code

```
(digit, index) => return digit.Length < index
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Simply because this overload is implemented as something like this (dropped generic to make it easier):

```
static IEnumerable<string> Where(string[] sequence, Func<string, int, bool> predicate)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach(var item in sequence)
    {
        if (predicate(item, index))
            yield return item;

        index++;
    }
}
```

So this implementation sends the index of the item to your lambda expression.

So, you call it like this:

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
                    "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var result = Where(digits, PredicateMethod);
```

The only difference here is that I converted the lambda to an actual method:

```
static bool PredicateMethod(string digit, int index)
{
    return digit.Length < index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two overloads of the `Where` method. One of them takes a `Func<string, bool>` and the other takes a `Func<string, int, bool>`. What you're calling here is obviously the latter.

The `Func<string, int, bool>` delegate represents a method that takes two parameters (an int and a string) and returns a `bool`. Your lambda expression has two parameters and returns a `bool`. Therefore the code compiles.

Now, how does the `Where` method know the index?

This invovles the inner workings of the `Where` method. By looking at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs), `Where` calls the `WhereIterator` method which has all the index logic in it:

```
int index = -1;
foreach (TSource element in source) {
    checked { index++; }
    if (predicate(element, index)) yield return element;
}
```